# Matlab: How to plot normal curve from mean and standard deviation

Tags: matlab, visualization

I have a mean and standard deviation, I want to plot a normal curve with no labels on the axis and no grid lines. I have searched and found this:

```
r = mean + std.*randn(100,1);
histfit(r)
```

But this has the histogram bars, and grid lines and axis tickers.

Thanks

Comment: Side note: both `mean` and `std` are functions in matlab, so it's not a good idea to use them as variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just compute the corresponding [Gaussian curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) and plot it.

#### Example

Let's plot a Gaussian curve with 4 mean and 0.2 standard deviation:

```
mu = 4;                                %// Mean
sigma = 0.2                            %// Standard deviation

%// Plot curve
x = (-5 * sigma:0.01:5 * sigma) + mu;  %// Plotting range
y = exp(- 0.5 * ((x - mu) / sigma) .^ 2) / (sigma * sqrt(2 * pi));
plot(x, y)

%// Hide ticks
set(gca, 'XTick', [], 'XTickLabel', [], 'YTick', [], 'YTickLabel', [])
```

The result is:

[image: result]

Comment: Cool this seems almost there, how do I hide the top and right axis ticks and also the labels on the x and y axis?

Comment: @Aly Just modify the `XTick`, `XTickLabel', `YTick` and `YTickLabel` properties as shown. I've amended the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use:

```
R = normrnd(mu,sigma)
normplot(R)
```

Comment: Note that `normplot` requires the Statistics Toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have mean and standard deviation, why can't you just plot this?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution

That's the function you're interested in.  Just loop over values in the range of

`(mean - 3*stddev) <= x <= (mean + 3*stddev)`

Comment: Better to use a vector in that range.  Looping may be easy to understand, but it's a terrible habit to get into.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Normal probability density function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/normpdf.html). This, combined with [Eitan T's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16133814/4368964), would give

```
mu = 4;                                %// Mean
sigma = 0.2                            %// Standard deviation

%// Plot curve
x = (-5 * sigma:0.01:5 * sigma) + mu;  %// Plotting range
plot(x, normpdf(x,mu,sigma));

%// Hide ticks
set(gca, 'XTick', [], 'XTickLabel', [], 'YTick', [], 'YTickLabel', [])
```

and would result in the same figure. Only that you would use a MATLAB in-built function instead of coding it on your own.